# jquery change event does not fire for dynamic generated dropdown

Tags: jquery

i generate one dropdown box through button click event. In this dropdown onchange event does not fire. Can anyone help me why this is heapped? code is below

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $('#pin').click(function() {
            var content='<select class="pincode"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option></select>';
            $("#test").append(content);

            });
        $(".pincode").change(function(){
            alert($(this).val());
        });     
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div {
            padding: 35px;
            float: left;
        }
        }
    </style>
    <title>New Web Project</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dynamic Drop Down using jQuery</h1>
    <div>
        <select class="pincode">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="test"></div>
    <input type="button" id="pin" value="pin" />
```

Comment: please accept the below upvoted answer if it is helpful.,

Answer (score 16):

You need to use delegation because the element is loaded dynamically and was not there when the event listener was created.

```
$(document).on('change',".pincode", function(){
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Please notice you have one extra `}` inside your style tags. Would be better to have this in the CSS file.

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F2KC6/)

Check this link about [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/). In the delegated events part one can read:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to 'the event handler'.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am new to jquery and can you explain me why Attach an event handler function?

Comment: @Harshit, its the same as in vanilla/plain javascript. The event handler is attached to a element and will fire on `change`. If the code is read and the element was not added yet then no event handler is attached and when the `change` happens it will not fire any action

Answer (score 1):

with Dynamic created-elements, it's better to use "on" and "off" to bind events

```
$(".pincode").on("change", function(){
            alert($(this).val());});
```